# Trouble Populating UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having trouble populating a subclassed UITableView.

All I am getting is a blank screen.

It is embedded into a `UIView` as such (`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are set in the `UITableViewController.h`):

```
    TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc] 
                                     initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 320.0, 
                           self.view.bounds.size.height);
    tableView.tableView.dataSource = tableView;
    tableView.tableView.delegate = tableView;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView.view];
```

---

Then, in the UITableViewController I create a dummy Array to use as a data source:

```
library = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Dummy 1",
                    @"Dummy 2",
                    @"Dummy 3",
                    @"Dummy 4", nil];
```

---

Then I do the required data source delegate methods as such:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

---

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                       numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int rows;
    if (section == 0) {
        rows = [library count];
    }
    else if (section == 1) {
        rows = 0;
    }
    return rows;
 }
```

---

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Missions Library"];
    }
    else {
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Acknowledgements"];
    }
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId 
                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                        reuseIdentifier:CellId];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [library objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

I have read numerous table view tutorials, and I cannot figure out the problem. I get no error message, just a blank a table view screen.

What did I do wrong?

**Couple of updates:**

1. If I do not add the tableView's view as a subview but call it directly, I get the header and footers displayed, but not the cells.
2. cellForRowAtIndexPath method does not get called at all (I checked it with NSLog). This explains why I do not get the cells.
3. The whole exercise is to have a grouped table view that only occupies the lower part of the screen. But my approach might not be the best way to achieve this...

Comment: are you using storyboards? i had a similar problem where i didnt set cell identifier in the storyboar try that.

Comment: No, I am not using neither interface builder nor storyboards. I am trying to do everything programmatically as I feel more control over what I am doing this way.

Comment: Are you hitting any breakpoints in any of these methods?

Comment: @GergelyKovacs, Why dont you subclass your current view controller as subclass of `TableViewController` and do it rather than adding tableView.view as its subview. That should be the issue here. If that is not possible, you need to subclass UITableView and not UITableViewController.

Comment: I do not have breakpoints, and reloadData did not help. :(

Comment: @ACB I add it as a view because I only need the tableview to occupy part of the screen. I am going to try to subclass UITableView ans see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @GergelyKovacs, Yes, check it and let me know.

Comment: @GergelyKovacs Have you verified the return value of numberOfRowsInSection: for both sections? Perhaps library is nil or empty when this method is called.

Comment: @GergelyKovacs, Where is your delegate and data source methods written? In tableview or self? because you are setting both as tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the TableViewController. Just add a UITableView.

Start with:

```
UITableView *tableData;
```

And then the methods for filling the table and adding it as a subview.

Comment: This worked, and I marked it as the right answer; although, to be fair, credit also goes to ACB and Darren because they also suggested the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is that your library array is being loaded with objects but the UITableView instance itself isn't getting notified of this (via reloadData). Also, keep in mind that calling

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId 
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

ensures that you'll get a cell so there is no need for:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellId];
}
```

As long as the identifier is properly set in the storyboard.

I could be wrong but I would need to know where the data population takes place.

Comment: Where do you call [self.tableView reloadData]? I added it to numerous places in my code but to no avail...

Comment: Sorry but your statement is incorrect. The OP stated this is all in code, no storyboard or xib. Calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: can return nil. The OP's code for cellForIndexPath: is correct.

Comment: Look at the UITableViewDataSource documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: Notice the difference between dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: @GergelyKovacs The correct place to call "reloadData" is right when your data is ready. Make sure the table is hooked up to an IBOutlet so this call goes back to it.

Comment: @Stavash Sorry, you didn't reply to me so I never saw your comment. You are correct. My statement was based on the wrong method. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing [self.tableView reloadData].

Also, if you're supporting ios 6.0+, use the method

```
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

when you are setting up your UITableView. This will ensure that

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

returns a cell, and not nil, so you won't have to do the if (cell == nil) check.

Comment: Where do you call [self.tableView reloadData]? I added it to numerous places in my code but to no avail...

Comment: Usually you set up Key value observing on the array that represents your model data, in this case, library. Every time that library's value changes, you call a method which calls [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: Try putting an NSLog on [library objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] before you set that as the text for the cell. Check that you're getting back a String there, and not nil

Comment: No. And not only that, the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath methods is not being called. Puzzler... :/

Comment: If the method isn't getting called, the chances are the problem is with setting up your delegates.
 
Maybe try making it tableView.tableView.dataSource = self; 
and tableView.tableView.delegate = self;

Comment: Can you clarify in your post, what did you subclass? UITableView or UITableViewController? Why are you using a subclass, and why are you initializing a TableViewController?

Answer (score 2):

If your adding a tableview to a UIViewController, you want to be adding a UITableView and not a UITableViewController.